# Openlayers. Reverse BBOX query strings params

Tags: openlayers, parameters

Using the BBOX strategy on OpenLayers (Last Stable Version) the URL is created using the LEFT, BOTTOM, RIGHT, TOP param order.

I need to send the request to an API REST in another order. I tried to replace the Bounds.toBBOX () function but it's seems not to be called.

Also, I have checked the openlayers code from Github (Strategy and Protocol files) but I can't find where is the URL being formated

The last thing I have tried is to replace the params on the new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP constructor but I can't replace the bbox query

**UPDATE**

This is the code I was using in the query to transform the projection coordinates creating a CLONE object of bounds. I imagine BBOX strategy will do a .toBBOX () call anyway to create the query string and bind to the URL after each drag of the map

```
var my_calculate_bounds = function (mapBounds) {

    // Block 
    messages.wait (i18n.api_messages.waiting_for_response) ;


    // Define mapBounds
    if ( ! mapBounds) {
        return ;
    }

    var center = mapBounds.getCenterLonLat ();
    var dataWidth = mapBounds.getWidth () * this.ratio;
    var dataHeight = mapBounds.getHeight () * this.ratio;

    // left bottom right top

    this.bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds (
        center.lon - (dataWidth / 2),
        center.lat - (dataHeight / 2),
        center.lon + (dataWidth / 2),
        center.lat + (dataHeight / 2)
    );

    this.bounds = this.bounds.clone().transform (
        MAP.map.getProjectionObject(),
        new OpenLayers.Projection ("EPSG:4326")
    );


    // Refresh zoom level protocol
    MAP.protocol.params.zoomlevel = MAP.map.getZoom() ;

} ;
```

Comment: Show us some code, surely you can just rearrange the values yourself when sending the request.

Comment: Is the URL you are talking about the one created by permalink?

Comment: Hi. The API has been updated to work with OpenLayers params order so the main problem is resolved.

Comment: The URL I was talking about is one generated by BBOX strategy and PROTOCOL when drag the map